# How to classifiy NER using sequence label/ IOB tag?

Tags: python, nlp, text-classification, named-entity-recognition, crf

I am trying to recognize and classify the entity types based on the IOB/Sequence labeling.

For example:

```
Alex  B-PER
Tan   I-PER
is O
a O
president O
. O
```

I only can classify it by token which mean it classify Alex  B-PER and Tan   I-PER as a different class/entity type.

So my question how to classify Alex B-PER and Tan  I-PER as one/same class which is PERSON?

Thank you.

Comment: As far as I understand your example, it is exactly the case that "Alex Tan" is a single chunk annotated with the class "PER", which most probably stands for "person". Conceptually, there are two levels of annotation: the BIO chunk boundaries, and the actual classes ("PER" etc.). The sequence labeller predicts them together, as if the combinations form a single "class". You might need to postprocess the output (like the sequence O–I, which cannot exist).

Answer (score 3):

All needed information is already contained in [BIO encoding](https://web.archive.org/web/20170805150451/https://lingpipe-blog.com/2009/10/14/coding-chunkers-as-taggers-io-bio-bmewo-and-bmewo/).

You just need to go through all token-label pairs: if you find B-X label, then it is start of X entity (in your example - it is pair `[Alex_B-PER]`) , so create new entity, which first token is the token with B_X label; while the next label is I-X, append corresponding token to the created X entity (in your example - it is pair `[Tan_I-PER`] - so your entity is `[Alex Tan_PER]`). If the next label is B-Y, you create new entity as before; if the next label is O, just go further.

Comment: That's mean I have to do this step before I classify it?

Comment: No, you have to do this step after obtaining "IOB/Sequence labeling"